# Происхождение слова «туземный»

Tags: этимология, лексика, история

Какова этимология слова «туземный»? Когда оно появилось в русском языке? Есть ли у него производные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ТУЗЕМНЫЙ ([**по словарю Даля**](http://tolkslovar.ru/t5656.html)):

местный, относящийся до известной страны, местности.
*Это наш туземный обычай. Туземные жители части Океании стоят на низшей степени человечества.*
Туземность, туземство ср. принадлежность к какой либо стране, земле, природство, землячество. *По туземности, ему искони коротко знакомы вел местные обычаи.*
Даровать кому либо туземство, признать гражданином своей страны, со всеми правами; дать гражданство, отуземить кого, принять его в свои сограждане. Туземец, -мка, здешний, тамошний уроженец, природный житель страны, о коей речь.

Происходит от праслав. , от кот. в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. тъземьць, тоземьць (также в знач. «иностранец», Хож. игум. Дан. 130), церк.-слав. туземьць наряду с русск.-церк.-слав. сеземьць. Из **ту-** (см. тут) и ***земьць** от земля (из словаря М. Фасмера).

Можно посмотреть разнообразие значений слова [**туземец**](http://www.orthodic.org/?searchCs=&searchRu=%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%86&type=ru&go.x=0&go.y=0) в Полном церковно-славянском словаре (с внесением в него важнейших древнерусских слов и выражений).

А производные нашлись такие ("ту" вошло в корень слова: **тузем**/н/ый):
туземец, туземка, туземность, туземство, туземно, туземский ("Туземак" — туземский ром), туземия, туземить, отуземить.

*Тебе, влюбленному **туземно**

в салатно-золотой стог сена,

завидую, тишайший колорист!*
В. Бобрецов

*Турусина — типъ московской барыни, весело, даже очень весело проведшей свою молодость и ударившейся на старость въ ханжество, выражающееся тоже **туземно:** покровительствомъ всевозможнымъ странным людямъ (юродивымъ, блаженнымъ и, вообще, бродягамъ)...*
Критическая литература о произведениях А. Н. Островского. (1868-1873 гг.)

*Народы, присоединенные к Российской империи, на официальном языке назывались **туземцами**. Владимир Даль выводит это слово от **"та земля" — "человек той земли"**. "**Туземить** кого — принять его в свои сограждане", — пояснял он.*
Учебное пособие "История Татарстана с древнейших времен до наших дней"

*Таблица нового **туземно-еврейского** алфавита. Ташкент, 1928*

[**акклиматизировать** (*acclimater*, нем.) akklimatisieren.1776. Лексис. Приживлять, приращивать, приурочивать, **отуземить**. Даль. (Исторический словарь галлицизмов русского языка)]